# Nested Inline in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following scenario where there are three models as follows which should be displayed nested in DJango admin. Am using Django 1.6 release and applied settings as put up in https://github.com/Soaa-/django-nested-inlines

However, it didnt turn up with the expected output. Is there any other solutions to implement nested inlines in Django. I'm a newbie to this framework. Kindly guide me to fix this issue.

model.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Detail(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    location = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Configuration(models.Model):
    detail = models.OneToOneField(Detail)
    content1 = models.IntegerField()
    content2 = models.IntegerField()
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inlines.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline, NestedStackedInline

from myapp.models import Project, Detail, Configuration

class ConfigInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Configuration
    extra = 1

class DetailInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Detail
    inlines = [ConfigInline,]
    extra = 1

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DetailInline]

admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nested-inline .

It has been updated to work with Django 1.6

Comment: also add nested_inline to installed apps

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've forgotten to set the ProjectAdmin as a `NestedModelAdmin`:

#### admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inlines.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline, NestedStackedInline

from myapp.models import Project, Detail, Configuration

class ConfigInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Configuration
    extra = 1

class DetailInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Detail
    inlines = [ConfigInline,]
    extra = 1

class ProjectAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DetailInline]

admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you import this below package first install this

> **pip install django-nested-admin**
> then add this in installed app list

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'nested_admin',
   ...
]
```

Now, you can import it.

```
from nested_inline.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline, NestedStackedInline
```